# Прокомментируйте: правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания, в особенности необходимо ли тире перед "что"

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Субъект вступает с сущим в отношение "занятия наукой", при этом вторгаясь в сущее таким образом, — что оно раскрывает само себя.

Comment: Примечание: интонационные тире не подходят для делового стиля (для документов).

Comment: Примечание 2: родительный падеж ("занятия") не подходит для кавычек (надо "занятие наукой"), если родительный падеж, то кавычки не ставятся. Но может, у вас множественное число (занятия — они).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед "что" тире не требуется от слова совсем.

Если нужно подчеркнуть последнюю фразу интонационным тире, то так:
*Субъект вступает с сущим в отношение "занятия наукой", при этом вторгаясь в сущее таким образом, что оно — раскрывает само себя.*
Перед "что" интонационное тире неуместно, так плохо звучит, это не применяется.

Answer (score -2):

Сочетание ‟занятия наукой” не следует брать в кавычки (конечно, если только это не ирония) и перед ‟что” не следует ставить тире. Также не следует писать всякую философскую шизу.